# HTML templates or React for Django front end?

Tags: python, django

I’m creating a big project with Django and wondering if it is sensible to use the HTML template structure for my front end or should I implement something like React? What are each of its benefits? Is it perfectly reasonable to use HTML templates for a big project? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Django templates are quite fully featured, and performant, and I'd use them if I could meet the requirements in my project with them alone. Adding react will increase the tooling you'll need and have to maintain, so my team only introduced it after we started to need user interfaces that were react-like (it started when we implemented an in-app to do list). So your project requirements will really dictate if you want to invest additional development and devops energy into react in order to have a more instant-update/native-app-like feel, or not.

If you are unsure, I'd recommend starting with templates and introducing react later. It's entirely possible to run an app that uses templates for 90% of your app and react only where it's needed (we do this).

Answer (score 0):

The thing with React is you need to have a good API in between your back-end and your front-end. I would recommend Django Rest Framework for that. Anyway, templates are nice to quickly get something up and running, something that is mostly display centered and you don't have to do too much scripting. React makes it easier to have a heavier front-end. However, templates can handle a lot of front end as well, just you won't get access to any of the nice benefits of React. I have used templates for a big project, and it worked nicely. I didn't have to build an API, and the templates easily interacted with my back-end. I am not sure exactly what kind of project you are doing, so these are just my recommendations.